# Sending File Over LAN

Tags: c#, encryption, public-key-encryption

## Simple Progarm To Send And Receive Files Over LAN Using Tcp

> i want encrypt the file and send it over the lan using both symmetric and asymmetric key approaches,an AES Encryption/Decryption First , then use RSA to Encrypt/Decrypt the symmetric key

## scenario example

> johan wants to send Alice a file securely johan must log into the application with his username and password if registered. 
>   If .not, johan must create a username and password If registered for the first time,
>    johan must generate the pair of key's (Public key and .Private key). 
>    Publish the public key and keep the private key secret To send the file to Alice,
>    johan generates a random key from the application to use in the encryption process of the file using AES. 
>    After the file encryption is done,
>    johan uses Alice's Published public key to encrypt the key using RSA and sends the file .
>    with the encrypted key When Alice receives the file,
>    she must log into the application and uses her stored private key to decrypt the RSA encrypted key. 
>    After that she uses the decrypted key to decrypt the file

### This is my code

> but i have difficult to understand the encryption Libraries in c# i don't know from where i will start please  anyone help me

## GUI

```
Groupbox called "Send" contain 2 textbox and 2 buttons
 1 - type : textbox name : SrcFilePathTextBox    for   Path
 2 - type : textbox name : DstAddressTextBox     for  Target IP
 3 - type : Button  name : SrcFilePathBrowseButton     for  open file dialog 
 4 - type : Button  name : SendButton        for  start sending Process

 groupbox called "receive" contain textbox and 2 buttons
 1 - type : textbox name : LocalhostInfoTextBox    for   Show PC LAN INFO
 2 - type : Button  name : LocalhostInfoLoadButton     for  Put Info In      textbox
 3 - type : Button  name : ReceiveWaitButton   for  start receiving Process
 and at the end progress bar
```

The Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace JustSendItPrototype
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void SrcFilePathBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SrcOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            SrcFilePathTextBox.Text = SrcOpenFileDialog.FileName;
    }
    const int PORT = 32665;
    const int BUF_SIZE = 65536;
    private void ReceiveWaitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 32665);
            tcpListener.Start();
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(networkStream))
                        {
                            string fileName = reader.ReadString();
                            long fileLength = reader.ReadInt64();
                            Debug.Print("FileName={0}, FileLength={1}", fileName, fileLength);
                            DstSaveFileDialog.FileName = fileName;
                            if (DstSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(DstSaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    if (fileLength > 0)
                                    {
                                        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                                        long bytesLeft = fileLength;
                                        while (bytesLeft > 0)
                                        {
                                            int bytesToTransfer = (int)Math.Min(bytesLeft, (long)BUF_SIZE);
                                            Debug.Print("Reading {0} B", bytesToTransfer);
                                            int bytesRead = reader.Read(buf, 0, bytesToTransfer);
                                            Debug.Print("Read {0} B", bytesRead);
                                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                                            {
                                                fileStream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                                                bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
                                                ProgressBar1.Value = 1000 - (int)(bytesLeft * 1000 / fileLength);
                                            }
                                            else
                                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Debug.Print("Sending confirmation");
                                    writer.Write((byte)1);
                                    MessageBox.Show(this, "File received successfully.", "Receive File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Receive File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string srcFilePath = SrcFilePathTextBox.Text;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(srcFilePath);
            long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(srcFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (TcpClient sendingClient = new TcpClient(DstAddressTextBox.Text, PORT))
                {
                    using (NetworkStream sendingStream = sendingClient.GetStream())
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(sendingStream))
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(sendingStream))
                            {
                                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(srcFilePath);
                                binaryWriter.Write(fileName);
                                binaryWriter.Write(fileLength);
                                Debug.Print("FileName={0}, FileLength={1}", fileName, fileLength);

                                if (fileLength > 0)
                                {
                                    byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                                    long bytesLeft = fileLength;
                                    while (bytesLeft > 0)
                                    {
                                        int bytesToTransfer = (int)Math.Min(bytesLeft, (long)BUF_SIZE);
                                        fileStream.Read(buf, 0, bytesToTransfer);
                                        Debug.Print("Sending {0} B", bytesToTransfer);
                                        binaryWriter.Write(buf, 0, bytesToTransfer);
                                        bytesLeft -= bytesToTransfer;
                                        ProgressBar1.Value = 1000 - (int)(bytesLeft * 1000 / fileLength);
                                    }
                                }

                                Debug.Print("Reading confirmation...");
                                byte answer = binaryReader.ReadByte();
                                if (answer == 1)
                                    MessageBox.Show(this, "File sent successfully.", "Send File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Send File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    private void LocalhostInfoLoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
            sb.Append("Hostname: ");
            sb.Append(hostname);
            sb.Append("\r\n");

            IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);
            foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
            {
                sb.Append("IP: ");
                sb.Append(address.ToString());
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }

            LocalhostInfoTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Send File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @JamesKPolk What is?

Answer (score 0):

<s>I am not at a computer right now, but the easiest way to accomplish your scenario is to use SslStream on both ends.</s>

On the server(Johan) once you have an incoming connection, you create an SslStream from the TcpStream. On the server, you will use SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(), this method accepts an X509Certificate (this will be your private key).

On the client(Alice) you will instead use SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient.

To both of these methods you can pass a Certificate Validation Callback. In your case you will only do this on client side, and check the given certificate is the one that was provided by Johan.

**EDIT: I have reread your question and as you requested, I have created an [example](https://github.com/VVlasy/JohanAliceExample) that first sends a key encrypted with RSA and uses that key to encrypt the following data**

**When some data is received, first the Key is decrypted, and then used for AES decryption. It is a very rough example, I have no registration and login and I have certificates stored so they both have private and public keys, but should be enough for you to accomplish your goal**

Comment: V thanks for your reply .. good idea but I I want AES and RSA encryption! I have a little bit about SSLstram so I will wait you to see The example